# How to add a custom dropdown menu in Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

I'm following these **steps** but it's not working. Could you help me? What I need is a dropdown of my account when the person starts the session

when I place this code my session icon disappears, try to change the header.panel to my icon class but it doesn't work for me please help.

[image]
[image]

[image]

**I have to get close to this from my custom header**

**Step 1** - Add in my file <Magento_luma_theme_dir>/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="header.panel">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

**Step 2** -
<Magento_Customer_module_dir>/view/frontend/templates/account/customer.phtml

```
<?php if($block->customerLoggedIn()): ?>
    <li class="customer-welcome">
        <span class="customer-name"
              role="link"
              tabindex="0"
              data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}'
              data-toggle="dropdown"
              data-trigger-keypress-button="true"
              data-bind="scope: 'customer'">
            <span data-bind="text: customer().fullname"></span>
            <button type="button"
                    class="action switch"
                    tabindex="-1"
                    data-action="customer-menu-toggle">
                <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Change')?></span>
            </button>
        </span>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "*": {
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": {
                    "components": {
                        "customer": {
                            "component": "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
            </script>
            <?php if($block->getChildHtml()):?>
            <div class="customer-menu" data-target="dropdown">
                <?php echo $block->getChildHtml();?>
            </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

**Step 3** app/design/frontend/Bss/default/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="header.links">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="header.links">
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\Customer" name="customer" template="Magento_Customer::account/customer.phtml" before="-"/>
            <block class="Magento\Customer\Block\Account\AuthorizationLink" name="authorization-link-login" template="Magento_Customer::account/link/authorization.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">10</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <move element="header" destination="header.links" before="-"/>
        <move element="register-link" destination="header.links"/>
        <move element="top.links" destination="customer"/>
        <move element="authorization-link" destination="top.links" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hello,**

Please do follow these steps to create the Drop-Down menu.

> Create the template file: Phtml

```
<div class="customer-menu">
 <span class="action toggle"  data-mage-init='{"dropdown":{}}' data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true">
     <span class="title"><?= __("Customer Menu"); ?></span>
 </span>
 <ul class="dropdown">
     <?= $block->getChildHtml() ?>
 </ul>
</div>
```

> Calls the blockn in XML where you want to show:

```
 <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="header-dropdown" template="Custom_Module::header-dropdown.phtml"/>
```

> Add design if you need, into less file.

```
.customer-menu {
.lib-dropdown();
```

}

> Move your links into dropdown with xml (example: my account link)

```
 <move element="my-account-link" destination="header-dropdown" />
```

**Thanks, this will help you out:)**

Comment: thank you, but I don't understand where to place those files. please help :/

Comment: you can add this on you theme dir: where you want to add the dropdown menu, like where you want to add this dropdown you can just add this code on related module or theme dir: of the module!